# Find range (position) of max value in array and store in an array variable?

Tags: vba, excel

Looking at the bottom of this code, I need to call upon a range and the range needs to be the position of the maximum value. Is there a way to store that position of that value into a variable and then use that variable as the range?

```
                   Dim Retest As Boolean

                        If (Abs(Suspect - mean) / SD) > LowConf Then

                            MsgBox "95% outlier: " & Suspect
                            Retest = True

                    End If

                        If (Abs(Suspect - mean) / SD) > HighConf Then

                            MsgBox "99% outlier: " & Suspect
                            Retest = True

                    End If




                        If Retest = True And Suspect = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(DataSet) Then

                           Range(?).Delete Shift:=xlUp

                        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the position of the maximum value of the range `A1:A10` and highlighting the value. Try the below example and modify it per your needs,

[image]

```
Sub find()
Dim i As Long, rownum As Integer
' variable i contains the max value of range A1:A10
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A1:A10"))
' rownum is the row number of the maximum value
rownum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(i, Range("A1:A10"), 0)
' use the rownum and highlight the cell
Range("A" & rownum).Interior.Color = vbGreen
End Sub
```

This vba code uses the `match` function to find the row number of the max value and use it in a range.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I tweaked it a bit to fit what I wanted but after that it was the last piece of the puzzle to my program. My first ever program! :) Thanks so much!

Comment: @Nick Thats nice to hear